# Chrome white border in dual monitor system

Tags: google-chrome, multiple-monitors, resolution

I'm using **Windows 10 RS3 in a dual monitor environment**, a display with resolution of 2560*1440 (QHD) at the left side and a FHD display at the right. (1920*1080)

By using the function called 'EXTEND' in windows to set up a dual screen environment. Windows recognizes the **QHD display as the main one** (since it's my laptop screen) and a **FHD monitor as the sub display.**

However, when I open Chrome as a new window in the FHD monitor, the **borders (boundaries) of the window turn white and thick** and I have no idea why it happens. I tried to find some details in some websites, but they didn't help me. **Other browsers such as Edge, Whale, and IE don't have this symptom; just Chrome has it now.**

**Is it a bug of the newest Chrome software?** I also added a link containing the image of the problem.

**Image link : https://i.stack.imgur.com/ONUTU.png**